# ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream giving null exception

Tags: java, android

So I have this:

```
parser.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/XML64_Decoded/res/sample.xml"), handler);
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at vms.main(vms.java:26)
```

Comment: Its not able to find your xml file, is my guess. Check the path once

Comment: i have been checking the path and the file is existing there so why i am still getting this error?

Comment: Try this : <Your_Class>.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample.xml")

Comment: not really clear on what you are saying...

Comment: is there an alternate way that this can get the file from the src or res folder? its dirving me crazy haha

Comment: I meant if your class names is MyClass. Then try parser.parse(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample.xml"),handler);

Comment: any other way of getting file input stream??

Comment: so i tried that method of parser.parse(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample.xml"),handler); and it still says InputStream Can NOt be null :((

Comment: I do not understand why this is such a problem as the file is located in the src folder and i have also tried to move the file into the res folder just to check and same result...!!!

Comment: any thing ?would help

Comment: @user3779673 If you are still looking for a solution can you please check whether my solution works for you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code is not able to get `InputStream` in your case and the following line may be causing it:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/XML64_Decoded/res/sample.xml")
```

It returns an instance of `InputStream` and I was facing the same problem. Before we proceed we need to figure out the location of xml file. If it is in same package as the class having this code is or in some other package. For example I am using this code in class `SAXParserDemo` and I have two xml files: `employee.xml` and `employeeInPckg.xml`. The first file is next to my class `SAXParserDemo` i.e. in same package so I can get `InputStream` using:

```
InputStream is1 = SAXParserDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("employee.xml");
```

The other file `employeeInPckg.xml` is at location `src/files/employee/xml/employeeInPckg.xml` and I can get `InputStream` as:

```
InputStream is2 = lassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getSystemResourceAsStream("files/employee/xml/employeeInPckg.xml");
```

The rules for searching are explained in the javadoc of [ClassLoader#getResource(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and the javadoc of [Class#getResource(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).